# Run iOS4.x simulator from Xcode 4.2 (4C199) downloaded 1st Nov 2011

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I've been using Xcode 3.x  but today (nov 1st 2011) have downloaded Xcode 4.2 (4C199) for the first time and installed it under a separate directory to Xcode 3.x.  (It is installed under DeveloperX4).

When I fire up Xcode 4, the only target simulator versions that I can see to run in are iOS5.0 simulators.  When the simulator runs I can use the "Hardware" menu option to change between iPad, iPhone Retina and iPhone devices but the Hardware Version only shows me 5.0 (9A334).

I've got my iOS deployment target set to iOS3.1 in the Build Settings for the target.

How can I run up iOS4.x simulator from this latest version of Xcode 4?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your deployment target to 4.3 in the Project Settings "Summary" tab:

[image: Xcode deployment target setting]

Comment: awesome thank you (I'm a little surprised that having the older 3.1 as the target didn't also let me see these additional simulator options, but changing up to 4.3 definitely did the trick).

Comment: You are right gamozzii, with the deployment target being 3.1 you are still able to run it on a 4.3 simulator, you just had to download the simulator first.  Changing the deployment target from 3.1 -> 4.3 however will prevent anyone with 4.2 and below from running your App.

Answer (score 5):

You can download iOS 4.3 simulators from the preferences menu -> downloads tab:

[image]